# FT4232HL interfaces not listing on VCP ports

Tags: usb, ftdi

I am currently using the FT4232HL from FTDI and Ubuntu 20.04. The device features 4 interfaces.
When plugging the device, only one of this interface is bound to the corresponding driver (ftdi_sio), and is the only interface accessible through ttyUSB0. The three others do not show. Why?

Comment: First thing to check is if that driver actually supports all 4 interfaces, or if it's a generic driver that also happens to work on the first port of the FT4232HL.

Comment: Have you downloaded the [Linux driver](https://ftdichip.com/drivers/vcp-drivers/) and followed [their installation guide?](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/AN_220_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_Linux-1.pdf) do you have the latest version (1.5.0)?

Comment: The VCP drivers are integrated into the kernel. Also, the drivers should support the four interfaces of the FT4232HL device

Comment: Kernel drivers may be out of date. Do you know *for a fact* that the kernel has the latest version?